# Hiding divs based on checkboxes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jQuery code:

```
<script> function hideMenteeQuestions() {
    $("#menteeapp").hide();
    $("textarea[name='short_term_goals']").rules("remove", "required");
    $("textarea[name='long_term_goals']").rules("remove", "required");
}

function showMenteeQuestions() {
    $("#menteeapp").show();
    $("textarea[name='short_term_goals']").rules("add", {
        required: true
    });
    $("textarea[name='long_term_goals']").rules("add", {
        required: true
    });
}

function hideMentorQuestions() {
    $("#mentorapp").hide();
    $("input[name='mentees']").rules("remove", "required");
}

function showMentorQuestions() {
    $("#mentorapp").show();
    $("input[name='mentees']").rules("add", {
        required: true
    });
}

</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#mentee").change(function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
        showMenteeQuestions();
      }else{
        hideMenteeQuestions();
      }
    });
    $("#mentor").change(function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
        showMentorQuestions();
      }else{
        hideMentorQuestions();
      }
    });

    $('#mentee').change();
    $('#mentor').change();

    });
    </script >
```

Also, here's the HTML for my checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" id="mentor" value="mentor"><span class="checkbox">Mentor</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" id="mentee" value="mentee"><span class="checkbox">Mentee</span>
```

It's supposed to hide certain divs based on the checkbox you're selecting. It works when you click the checkboxes. However, I also want to trigger the change functions on page load. For some reason, it's only calling the first change function, which in this case is for `#mentee`. If I change the order, then the other one works. It never gets into the second `change()` call.

Any ideas?

Comment: looks like a typo ... try a jsfiddle

Comment: Is the if statement inside of `$("#mentee")` supposed to be commented out?

Comment: Sorry its not supposed to be commented out.

Comment: Works for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hXvE2/).

Comment: It appears that the issue is in one of the four functions you call but have not posted the code for: `showMenteeQuestions`, `hideMenteeQuestions` (I'd assume one of these since the script stops working after the first `alert`).

Comment: Updated the code with the rest of the functions.

Comment: What version of JQuery is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by changing the `hideMenteeQuestions()` and `showMenteeQuestions()` functions:

```
function hideMenteeQuestions(){
  $("#menteeapp").hide();
  $("textarea[name='short_term_goals']").removeClass('required');
  $("textarea[name='long_term_goals']").removeClass('required');
}

function showMenteeQuestions(){
  $("#menteeapp").show();
  $("textarea[name='short_term_goals']").removeClass('required').addClass('required');
  $("textarea[name='long_term_goals']").removeClass('required').addClass('required');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create a function that determines which box is checked and hides the div's accordingly. Then you can use that function as a callback for the change event as well as on load. for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  toggleDivs = function () {
    if($("#mentor").is(':checked')){
      hideMentorQuestions();
      showMenteeQuestions();
    }else if($("#mentee").is(':checked')){
      hideMenteeQuestions();
      showMentorQuestions();
    }
  }

  $('#mentor, #mentee').change(toggleDivs);
  toggleDivs();
});
```

It also seems to me like you want either-or in which case I would recommend using radio buttons rather than checkboxes

Comment: I wouldn't use that last line - put _everything_ inside `document.ready()` and then that line should just read `toggleDivs()`.  As is you're making `toggleDivs` a global function.

Answer (score 2):

Your description suggests that you have not properly wrapped your Javascript into a `document.ready()` function, i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

I expect what's happening is that one of your functions is throwing an exception because the DOM isn't yet properly ready.

Even if you *have* got a `document.ready` handler, I think the stuff about exceptions is still probably true - some condition is failing in both functions, but only on first load.

Comment: in which case, what does your javascript error console tell you?